# Unity UI InputField does not consume the keyboard input

Tags: unity

Unity UI:  I have an input field in which I can type.  Unfortunately, when I hit any of the movement keys, such as the space bar, I move while I'm typing which is not the effect I want.  Is there a way to force the input field to consume the keyboard input so it doesn't also get picked up by the game?  Or do I have to write the code in my game to do that for me.  (Seems like it should be configurable at least).

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable to indicate at what point you should enter text and when not, then constrain the actions of his character in relation to the bool, ie:

```
public bool keyboradisactive;

if(keyboradisactive==false){
    // actions of the character
}else{
}
```